# Large degrees of freedom (df) reported in lmer model

Tags: lme4-nlme, degrees-of-freedom

I am running a 3-way interaction linear mixed effect model using `lmer` function to see how reaction time varies as a function of age (older vs. younger), task (AJ vs. GJ), and repetition of images (4 in total). In my study, all the subjects viewed the same set of images 4 times (thus 4 repetitions) regardless of the tasks they were assigned to.

My dataset looks like this:

```
  Rep        RT Imagename     Age Task  ID
1   4 1359.8449 M132.jpg   older   AJ 412
2   2  809.5769 M134.jpg   older   AJ 403
3   1  877.9370 F127.jpg younger   GJ 108
4   2 1937.6835 M104.jpg younger   AJ 313
5   4 2046.2428 M119.jpg younger   AJ 307
6   1 1888.7130 M112.jpg   older   AJ 419
7   2  683.4228 F111.jpg   older   GJ 223
8   2  698.0348 M125.jpg younger   GJ 114
```

To avoid confusion and get to the point, here is a simplified version of the 3-way interaction lmer model I create. Repetition of images is a fixed effect. Subject ID and Imagename are treated as random effects.

```
RT_model = lmer(RT ~ Rep + (1|Imagename) + (1|ID), data=fullset)
```

Model summary:

```
summary(RT_model)

REML criterion at convergence: 407026.7

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.6615 -0.5036 -0.1204  0.3170  6.6692 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 filename (Intercept)   4941    70.29  
 ID       (Intercept) 169888   412.18  
 Residual             246970   496.96  
Number of obs: 26641, groups:  filename, 120; ID, 80

Fixed effects:
             Estimate Std. Error        df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  1279.451     47.032    84.940    27.2   <2e-16 ***
Rep           -80.283      2.878 26448.916   -27.9   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

In the output, I noticed the `degrees of freedom` for Rep is very large, which may be the reason why I have a tiny p value associated with it. It seems like the test is using the power as if each trial is it's own observation, but I'd expect the power of looking at it by subject (i.e., 80 subjects not 26000+ trials). I don't know if this means my model isn't set up appropriately, or if this is something I should be worried at all? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

I found someone else asked a similar question before but no answer: [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61250938/why-such-large-degrees-of-freedom-on-some-levels-in-a-linear-mixed-effects-model)

anova result if helps:

```
anova(RT_model)

Type III Analysis of Variance Table with Satterthwaite's method
       Sum Sq  Mean Sq NumDF DenDF F value    Pr(>F)    
Rep 195519091 65173030     3 26443  264.01 < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Thank you in advance for your help.